# Is there a widget that simulates a disk activity LED?

Tags: disk

I'm looking for a widget or such that simulates the disk activity light that my Lenovo laptop ought to have but doesn't.  **I don't want any more information than that** -- no usage graphs, etc.  Just a binary indicator that says that the disk is working.

Does such exist?

Answer (score 1):

[indicator-multiload](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=indicator-multiload&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) from the default repository is as close to this feature as I can find. It displays a small rectangle in the notification area.  By default it shows the CPU usage.  You can change the preference and select which usage from 6 choices including Harddisk.  You can simply remove the check mark from Load and checkmark Harddisk.

The `binary indicator` criterion is a vertical line on or off.

I need this functionality because, while the monitors are on my desk, the computers are hidden, so I can't see the flashing lights on them.  Also, like you, one of the computers is a mini-box, that doesn't have an harddisk LED.

Since this question was high on my google search for a solution, I'm sure it will benefit others looking for something similar.

Hope you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything which specifically caters to your problem but `wmhdplop` seems to do a similar job. Although it seems quite old, it might do the job.

[image]

For more information, visit [this](http://hules.free.fr/wmhdplop/) website.

Comment: wmhdplop seems much more elaborate than what I need, though I might turn to it if I get desperate enough.  Thanks for the pointer.